# Shift in counting inversions merge sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

So I found [this implementation](https://www.techiedelight.com/inversion-count-array/) of an algorithm for counting inversions. Generally I understand it, but I'm not sure why for finding mid point the author used shift
`int mid=(low+((high-low)>>1));` could someone please explain it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most likely explanation would be that the author has a highly outdated understanding of optimization and performance. Or maybe they were trying to show of.

Answer (score 2):

The "obvious" way to write `int mid=(low+((high-low)>>1));` is `int mid=(low+high)/2;`. The latter has two deficiencies.

1. Integer overflow. If the array is very long, `low+high` can overflow the bounds of `int`, which is undefined behavior in C++. In Java, it was the root cause of an [infamous bug](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).
2. Efficiency. Good compilers will not emit an (expensive) division instruction for division by two. Unless the compiler can deduce somehow that `low+high` is not negative, however, it can't just rewrite the division (i.e., truncating division per the C++ standard) to a shift (equivalent to floor division), since the results differ for negative dividends. Typically it will emit instructions to compute the sign bit and add it in, which requires a couple of extra instructions (though cheap ones).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, shift to the left means getting half of your variable.. it should be faster then dividing by 2 because you only push your binary number one step to the left, that's why he used this nice little trick